# ClassCastException on upcasting

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception

I've got 2 classes: SubEditor and Editor.

`public class SubEditor extends Editor {`

I am creating a SubEditor object and trying to cast it to Editor, but I'll get a ClassCastException:

```
try {
    (Editor) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("bla.SubEditor").newInstance();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    try {
        Object object = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("bla.SubEditor").newInstance();

        // prints "false":
        System.out.println(object instanceof Editor);

        // prints "bla.SubEditor":
        System.out.println(object.getClass().getCanonicalName());

        // prints "Super: bla.Editor":
        System.out.println("Super: "+object.getClass().getSuperclass().getCanonicalName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do sth
    }
}
```

How is it even possible that I get "false" on "SubEditor instanceof Editor"?

The Exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: bla.SubEditor cannot be cast to bla.Editor`

Hope you can help!

Greetings,

Martin

Comment: JSonEditor or SubEditor? This is confusing.

Comment: Sorry for that, I mean SubEditor. Updated my description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be, that the two classes are being loaded using different ClassLoader instances.

I think you can check if this is the case by comparing the two class loaders:

```
Editor.getClassLoader().equals(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
```

Using different class loaders results in two different `Class` objects, hence the `ClassCastException`

Comment: In fact, you are right. But how could it be? Both classes are on the same runnable created by Eclipse. I've never had such problems while developing under Netbeans...

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps if you could post more details it'd be more clear. As for the solution to your problem, it seems like `Editor.getClassLoader().loadClass("bla.SubEditor")` instead of `(Editor) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("bla.SubEditor")` should work

Comment: Okay, thanks!

I figured out, that eclipse uses the class loader `java.net.URLClassLoader`, whereas the system ClassLoader is an instance of `sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader`. Thank you very much; but this would also mean that I would be able to load 2 classes with the same name (e.g. 2 times the class `bla.SubEditor`) by different class loaders?

Comment: That's exactly what caused your problem, so yes, this is possible